# kolmogorov complexity for finite Language?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, programming-languages, turing-completeness, kolmogorov-complexity

In lectures my professor proved that there is no Turing machine that for every x it calculates k(x).

On the other hand, I saw a claim online that for finite language L there is a Turing machine that calculate k(x) for every x in the finite language L.

But how does it work, why is this possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a property specific to kolmogorov complexity - it works with any function over strings (no matter what the function is!).

Since $L$ is finite, then also the set $K:=\{(x,k(x))\mid x\in L\}$ is finite.

Therefore there exists some TM that has the entire set $K$ stored in a large table. When the TM is given input $x$, it will look through this table and output the appropriate $k(x)$.

Comment: Sorry but this made me more confused, read this: "It has been formally proven that one can't compute the Kolmogorov complexity of a string." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836134/how-to-compute-kolmogorov-complexity-of-an-algorithm

Comment: In this question you asked "how to compute the Kolmogorov complexity of every string **in a finite language $L$**". In the link, they answer for "how to compute the Kolmogorov complexity of **all** possible strings". Those two are totally different questions

Comment: I didn't get that.

Comment: I claim that the one of the strings in L happens to be the lowest counterexample to the Collatz conjecture, and the string is longer than the program which brute-forces the Collatz conjecture. How does a Turing machine calculate k(this string)? there's probably a direct reduction to the halting problem but I am too lazy to find it.

Comment: There is no reduction, if your only task is to compute this value. Since its a single string, then $k(s)$ is some value (doesnt really matter what). Now, I claim there exists a TM which just outputs this $k(s)$ without even computing anything. This TM is hard-wired to output the specific value of $k(s)$, be it $5$, $100$ or $2021$.